# Is there any possible way to get findout extreme points exactly on static image in python?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to findout extreme points of a image(cloth). I have tried with https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-co-ordinates-of-contours-using-opencv-python/
but i need to findout like this,[image]

But the current issue is for some images it is detecting currectly and for some images it is not.
Can anyone help on this?

the successed image is,

[image]

the failed image is,
[image]

Original image of the failed one is,
[image]

Am I doing any wrong methods here? If yes, please suggest me the right one!

Comment: Some images are difficult to process.  Show us one of the images that failed.

Comment: See the edited part of the question @TimRoberts

Comment: Can you also show the original image of the failed one?

Comment: @NiteyaShah I uploaded the new one. Pls check it

Comment: Well, the label is, in fact, the strongest edge in that image.  cv2.findContours has a lot of options.  You will need to experiment.

Comment: contours, _= cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE,
       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
I used in the code like this.. @TimRoberts

Comment: I know that.  You will have to adjust those parameters and see if anything works better.

Comment: @TimRoberts will floodfill opencv work in my case?

Comment: Are all your images in a white background? If so you can probably filter out the other colors very aggresively, and then apply your filter.

Comment: Can you please show me some examples?

Comment: floodill fills an area of similar colors with a solid color.  Is that what you need to do?  I thought you were looking for the coordinates of the edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following method.

- change contour approximation variable according to your desired number of points. I have choose `0.0035`.

```py
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("image.png")

gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, threshold_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("threshold_image", threshold_image)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold_image, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
selected_contour = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(selected_contour, 0.0035 * cv2.arcLength(selected_contour, True), True)

cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)

for point in approx:
    x, y = point[0]
    string = str(x) + " " + str(y)
    cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 2, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, string, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0))

cv2.imshow("cordinate image", image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

| Threshold Image | Cordinate Image |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: Will the count of points detected in variable 'approx' change? Because sometimes the count is 20,and sometimes it is 21. If it changes, is there any method to make it constant ? Please suggest @Vatsal Parsaniya